# Disable VSCode prompt: "Do you want to save your workspace configuration"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the latest, released version of VSCode, at the time of this writing (2018-Jan-29; version 1.19.3), I see the following behavior (which is unnecessarily time-consuming, for my needs):

Whenever I attempt to close a window that has files open from multiple, disparate directories, I get the following prompt:

"Do you want to save your workspace configuration as a file?"

A set of buttons is also presented, offering me options.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot of prompt]

This prompt does not come up if I try to close a window with a single file being open, or a single directory.

Here is an example of how to launch VSCode from an OS command prompt, to reproduce this prompt:

code path/to/DirectoryA path/to/DirectoryB

I rarely want, or need, to save a new workspace.  I would rather this prompt never appear.  I am ok creating workspaces through other means, if and when necessary.

Is there a way to disable this prompt via one or more setting(s) in VSCode?

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issue Untitled.code-workspace file being created as I just close my laptop and never properly close Vs code.
I would delete them manually but somehow Git was still tracking these files whenever I push my code to the branch.

In any case we want to stop these files from being generated for that purpose follow the steps below:

`Go to code -> preferences -> settings -> under commonly used -> Files:Exclude -> Add Pattern ->  **/.code-workspace`

that would disable the prompt and no such files would be created again.

#disable-vscode-prompt #untitled.code-workspace #disable #autosave #vscode-workspace-disable #workspace #vscode-workspace

Comment: I tried this workaround, but the prompt in the OP still appeared.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by adding following in keybindings.json -

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+w",
    "when": "!editorIsOpen && !multipleEditorGroups",
    "command": "workbench.action.quit"
  }
```

Normally, cmd+w will close the editor window (with checks for unsaved as well), and when no editor window is open, it quits the app.

Comment: This is the only solution that delivered what I was looking for - always reopen all files (even "unsaved" files) when I restart VS Code, without any prompts to save when I quit. I was able to make this change through the UI rather than directly editing the `keybindings.json` file. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `K`), search for `workbench.action.quit`, and add `Ctrl` + `W` (or `Cmd` + `W` on a Mac) as a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my extension to quit vscode when all editors are closed

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Hai.AlwaysOpenWorkspace

The trick is to call `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.quit');` when all editors are closed.

`workbench.action.quit` will quit vscode without any prompts

Answer (score 1):

That should be supported with VSCode 1.86 (Jan. 2024), with [issue 187794](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187794)

> ### Add the option to skip the prompt to save the workspace config
>
> When opening multiple folders at once, and then either closing the window or selecting other folders, a prompt appears, asking the user (with the message “`Do you want to save your workspace configuration as a file?`”) if it wants to Save/Not Save, or Cancel the action.

---

It is fixed by [PR 200114](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/200114):

> `window.confirmSaveUntitledWorkspace`:
>
> Controls whether a confirmation dialog shows asking to save or discard an opened untitled workspace in the window when switching to another workspace
>
> default: true

Available in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) now.

Comment: Perfect! Happy to hear it's being supported as a first class configuration

Answer (score 0):

@HaiFengKao's comment mentions `workbench.action.quit` that quits vscode without any prompts.

Shortcut for it is `Ctrl + Q` but it quits all windows :(