# Disable VSCode prompt: “Do you want to save your workspace configuration”?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently using vs_code on Ubuntu, but I meet the same problem on Mac0S 'multiple desktops'.

**WHAT I WANT**
Several vs_code windows on different 'ubuntu workspaces', but all on my app folder.

**MY WAY OF DOING**
I start vs_code from the command line inside my app repo: `code .`
Then, with `Ctrl + Shft + P`, I select  '*Workspaces: Duplicate Workspace in New Window*'.
Next I move the new window to a new ubuntu workspace.

**MY PROBLEM**
Every time I close a vs_code window created that way, it always prompts me :

[image: Do you want to save your workspace configuration as a file ?]

As you can see, 'Save' button is the default.
It's annoying as I always have to click on 'Don't Save'.

**MY NEED**

- a user setting to deactivate the prompt on new workspace exit ?
- a way around to achieve what I want without a mandatory prompt ?

PS: I know there's a similar Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508313/disable-vscode-prompt-do-you-want-to-save-your-workspace-configuration), but it's 2 years old now and doesn't have a compelling answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable VSCode prompt: "Do you want to save your workspace configuration"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508313/disable-vscode-prompt-do-you-want-to-save-your-workspace-configuration)

Comment: Hey @HaiFengKao ! Thanks for replying. I had a look at this thread again. Your extension doesn't provide an answer to my need, but your comment did help.
From now on, I will use `Ctrl+Q` to close my vs_code windows, it skips the prompt !

Comment: I tried to convince the VSCode dev that workspace config is not that important without any success (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108201). `Ctrl+Q` is not a perfect solution because it will close all windows, not the current one. You may potentially lose your unsaved data in other windows. I think we have to submit the issue again after the dev is retired or quit his job :(

Comment: You're right `Ctrl + Q` is actually not at all what I expected it to be, I forgot to rollback my edit

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by adding following in keybindings.json -

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+w",
    "when": "!editorIsOpen && !multipleEditorGroups",
    "command": "workbench.action.quit"
  }
```

Normally, cmd+w will close the editor window, and when no editor window is open, it quits the app.